# pointing angular client to pact mock service

Tags: angular, jestjs, pact, angular-test

I use jest-pact and I try to create pact test for a service. I've already tried to point the service call explicitly to pact mock service (which I run on `localhost:8181`), but I got a pact verification error:

```
 Missing requests:
        GET /proxy/calendar/days?from=2020-12-31&to=2021-01-01
```

From logs I'm sure that Pact is registered, so it has to be problem with sending the request to pact mock service, but I don't have a clue how to solve it, since I'm a newbie in testing angular apps. Snippets below.

### Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CalendarService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getDays(): Observable<Day[]> {
    return this.http.get<Day[]>(`http://localhost:8181/proxy/calendar/days?from=2020-12-31&to=2021-01-01`);
  }
}
```

### Pact

```
pactWith({consumer: 'ui', provider: 'calendar', port: 8181, cors: true, logLevel: 'trace'}, provider => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [
        CalendarService
      ]
    });
  });

  describe('request for date range', () => {
    const specificDateExpectation = {
      date: iso8601Date('2020-12-31')
    };

    beforeEach(async () => {
      const getSpecificDateRange = new Interaction();
      getSpecificDateRange
        .uponReceiving('a request for specific date range')
        .withRequest({
          method: 'GET',
          path: '/proxy/calendar/days',
          query: {
            from: '2020-12-31',
            to: '2021-01-01'
          }
        }).willRespondWith({
          body: eachLike(specificDateExpectation, {min: 2}),
          status: 200,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }
      );

      try {
        await provider.addInteraction(getSpecificDateRange);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });

    it('should return information', async () => {
      const service = TestBed.get(CalendarService);
      await service.getDays()
        .toPromise().then(response => {
          expect(response[0].date).toBeInstanceOf(Date);
        });
    });

  });

});
```